# Paper BG Image: Make It Appear To Fill Window

Tags: html, css

I want to use a background image like the one below as the background of a site.  The problem is, I don't want it to tile.  I want the top edge to be the top edge of the window, side edges to be the side edges of the window, and bottom edge to be the bottom edge of the window.  The middle portions, both horizontally and vertically, should repeat in a natural looking way to fill up all the space, making it appear that the paper is the size of the browser window.  Is there a good way to do this?

[image]

Comment: There are two possible appearances: 1) the background doesn't scroll, it's fixed. So content scrolls over it. 2) the background repeats, so it smoothly scrolls along with the content. Which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this: http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/ ( Note that this is not the only background stretching script ) Upside with these is that it keeps the aspect ratio of the image.

Dunno if keeping the aspect ratio is necessary or even desirable in your case..?

---

IF i wanted to go all extreme on this background i would:

1. Take the basic grid and its surface structure and repeat that throughout the
   site bg.
2. Take the "shadows" on the sides and place them fixed on each side
   repeating them to whatever direction is needed

If i had all these elements in their own layers. Though that wouldnt be hard to fabricate.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution: make four `<div>`s:

`#top` with the top shadow
`#left` with the left shadow
`#right` with the right shadow
`#bottom` with the bottom shadow

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div> <!--Main content of site--> </div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
```

Style them with your preferred widths and `position:absolute`, and use clips of the original background image to fill them in, here's an example:

```
#top{
    height:50px;background:transparent url("top-background.png") 0px 0px no-repeat;
}
```

Then, you can just `repeat` a small grid clip of the original background image set as the `background-image` of `<body>`, like so:

```
body{
    background: transparent url("page-background.png") 0px 0xp repeat;
}
```